# Except is not working while comparing two lists

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have two lists which are of same dto.I am saving locally in sqlite and camparing with server data.

var notInlList = localList.Except(serverList).ToList();

but here comrator showing as null,but serverList contains 10 items and localList contains 16 items.

Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: what is your goal ? That `notInList` becomes a list with 6 elements ?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Greggz,I just want to remove those extra data.But here I am not getting that 6 elements.

Comment: And are `localList` and `serverList` populated when you are going to apply the `Except` ?

Comment: Oh I know the problem. Can you show me how does the `serverList` objects look ? You need to apply a custom comparer. `Except` needs to know how to compare the elements, and you're not telling him how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason

> If you want to compare sequences of objects of some custom data type,
>   you have to implement the
>   T:System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer` generic interface in a
>   helperclass. The following code example shows how to implement this
>   interface in a custom data type and provide
>   M:System.Object.GetHashCode and M:System.Object.Equals(System.Object)
>   methods.

You will encounter some examples for how to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` here
[MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)